# Magento with Varnish - var/cache folder still being used

Tags: cache, magento2.4, varnish

I have a Magento store configured with Varnish. When everything is up to date site is fast. If I change something in the backend it doesn't get reflected on frontend unless I manually delete var/cache/mage--* folders.

By the looks of the documentation, this folder should be empty after I configured Varnish.

How do I debug this?

Comment: Can you confirm you have followed all the steps mentioned here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html

Comment: Yes, I can confirm I followed all those steps, plus more from other guides.

Comment: in your varnish vcl comment out the unset resp.http.X-Varnish command and then restart varnish - if varnish is working you will see an x-varnish and x-magento-cache header being sent when you load a page. x-magento-cache will show HIT or MISS depending on if the page is cached or not. If you don't see this header varnish is not configured correctly.

Comment: @paj did what you told, there's no x-magento-cache, but there is x-varnish. Maybe because this ecommerce is behind cloudflare?

Comment: Well the varnish header shows that you are talking to the varnish server, if you are in production mode the other headers might not be shown - I am not sure about that - if you still have files being produced in var/cache then your magento varnish configuration is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, shop is in production mode. Main issue being is that, when I update some content, that doesn't reflect on the frontend. I have to, manually, clean the contents from var/cache/ and restart Varnish. It seems updating from backend doesn't invalidate cache OR something else is caching the old content before we have the chance to access the new content. I already disabled the Amasty Cache Warmer we were using to try to affect the behavior.

Comment: Your varnish configuration is incorrect. Double check all your settings again...

Comment: @paj may I post my default.vcl so you can help me understand it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't mean the vcl, I mean the magento config.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Varnish configuration with [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)

Use the command

```
n98-magerun2.phar config:show | grep full_page_cache
```

You should see something like the following where *magento2_php-apache_1* is the hostname of your Magento 2 server and *backend_port* is the tcp port of the content (magento 2) server

```
system/full_page_cache/caching_application - 2
system/full_page_cache/varnish/access_list - magento2_php-apache_1
system/full_page_cache/varnish/backend_host - magento2_php-apache_1
system/full_page_cache/varnish/backend_port - 8080
system/full_page_cache/varnish/grace_period - 300
```

You should also confirm your `env.php` is configured with an `http_cache_host`

```
'http_cache_hosts' => [
    [
        'host' => 'varnish',
        'port' => '6081'
    ]
],
```

The port here is the port Magento uses to communicate with the varnish server. You can also set this configuration with

```
magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=127.0.0.1:6081
```

The varnish vcl should also be configured correctly with the port of your content (magento) server

```
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Don’t get the ports mixed up :

- By default Varnish is configured to listen for incoming external client http requests on TCP 6081.
- The backend_port configured in admin is only used for the vcl config generation.
- The env.php http_cache_hosts port is the port used to communicate with varnish.

Comment: Since my varnish and my magento are on the same server, localhost and/or 127.0.0.1 should be correct, right? Also, varnish is running on port 6082, so it should be that port, correct?

Comment: 6082 is the varnish admin port. The port you configure in Magento is your Magento servers http port, if varnish is using TCP80 then it will be something else i.e. 8080 - 6082 is not correct.

Comment: Stupid mistake! I'll edit accordingly and provide feedback. Thanks @paj !